Dired: Changing compression algorithm
In dired, if I press Z on a file it compresses it using gzip.
Is there a value I can change/key I can press so that it uses a different compression algorithm? Such as lzma for instance?

Try defining dired-compress-file-default-suffix (it is nil by default, and in that case .gz wins):
(setq dired-compress-file-default-suffix ".lz")

Then add a stanza to dired-compress-file-alist in order to teach dired how to use lzip to do the compression:
(add-to-list 'dired-compress-file-alist '("\\.lz\\'" . "lzip -9 %i"))

%i is a placeholder for the name of the input file. Do C-h v dired-compress-file-alist to check how the other entries look.
Assuming you have lzip installed, that's what's going to be used for the compression. Read the manual page for lzip to see what options it takes: e.g. you can add -9 to the command (as I did above) to achieve higher (but slower) compression.
EDIT in response to a comment: You can add your own function easily enough and bind it to a free key in the dired-mode-map keymap like this:
#+begin_src elisp
  (defun my/dired-do-compress-lzip ()
    (interactive)
    (let ((dired-compress-file-default-suffix ".lz"))
      (dired-do-compress)))

  (define-key dired-mode-map (kbd "z") #'my/dired-do-compress-lzip)
#+end_src

You should also set dired-compress-file-default-suffix back to nil: we use gzip as the compression method globally, but the default suffix is overridden temporarily while the function above runs.
I found that z is free in the keymap, so I chose it as the key to bind the new function to. That way, Z compresses with the default nil value of dired-compress-file-default-suffix and z compresses with the let-bound value of that variable set to .lz.
This is pretty much an ugly hack though: not only would you have to write another function for yet another compression method, but even worse, you would have to find a free key in the keymap to bind the new function to. And you would have to remember those keys.
You might want to ask the question in your comment as a different question here - or better, you might send an RFE to the Emacs devs with M-x report-emacs-bug: IMO a good solution would involve modifying the dired-do-compress function to present a menu of choices if requested, and that would require some re-design, and changes to both the code and the documentation of Emacs.

Thank you NickD. Your answers are always helpful and thorough. Is there a way/keybind to change the compression algorithm every time? Maybe with a prefix or something?

I added a simple but hackish method to the answer. There are various possibilities but it would be better if you asked that question separately. Any possible solution would have to use the structure above, but then it becomes a problem of interactively selecting a suffix which has nothing to do with dired, compression or anything else discussed here. It's more like "how do you set up a menu for easy interactive choice?"
